# Angular animations with enter and leave

Tags: angular, animation, angular8, ivy

I have the following scenario: I am trying to make a two level menu with angular. The first level is always shown. The second level is opened/closed when I click the parent element. And I want the submenu animate in.

My code till now looks like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="isFolder || isItem" class="menu-item" [ngClass]="{ 'menu-open': isMenuOpen, 'disabled': !isSelected, 'open': isOpened }">
  <div class="content" tabindex="0" (click)="click($event)">
    <div class="icon" title="{{ (!isMenuOpen ? item.properties.textKey : '') | translate }}">
      <fa-icon [icon]="item.properties.icon" [fixedWidth]="true"></fa-icon>
    </div>
    <span class="text" [translate]="item.properties.textKey"></span>
    <div *ngIf="isFolder" class="chevron">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['scs', 'ui-menu-opened']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul *ngIf="isOpened" @openClose class="sub-menu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item.subMenu">
      <li *ngxPermissionsOnly="subItem.permissions">
        <cockpit-menu-item [item]="subItem"></cockpit-menu-item>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'cockpit-menu-item',
  templateUrl: './menu-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-item.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ height: '0px' }),
        animate('2s', style({ height: '*' })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('2s', style({ height: '0px' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class MenuItemComponent extends AbstractUnsubscribeComponent implements OnInit {
```

The relevant part is:

```html
<ul *ngIf="isOpened" @openClose class="sub-menu">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item.subMenu">
```

The leave animation works as expected but the enter not. It seems that with the use of *ngFor the content is constructed at a point where the height evaluation has already been done. So the submenu stays closed until the animation time is elapsed and then appears immediately.

I have tried the following and it works:
* Replace the *ngFor with some static content.
* Use a fixed height instead of "*" in the animation.

But since the items can vary both approaches are not really feasible.

Any ideas?

Thx
Markus

PS.: Since a few third party libraries we use still do not work with angular 9 I am still with angular 8 and ivy enabled.

Comment: did you try adding a `trackBy` to your `*ngFor`? It could be that it keeps re-rendering and, because of that it cannot calculate the right height. You can also try to set `height: 'auto'`. If that doesn't work, can you try to create a stackblitz which illustrates your issue?

Comment: Hello, thx for the suggestions. I have tried both, but neither of them did help.
I also tried to replicate the issue on StackBlitz, but until now I was not able to. There must be something special in my scenario. The structure of the menu items is fairly complex with heavy use of flex. So for now I will continue to investigate...

Br Markus